# How to obtain GridStreamer on remote node without streaming configuration

Tags: gridgain

In GridGain 6, can I obtain GridStreamer instance on remote node and use it to addEvents?

The idea is that I need a node, which can generate data for stream processing, but not to participate in processing itself.

All nodes, launched with StreamConfiguration section automatically participate in processing of events. And if node is launched without  StreamConfiguration section - then its Grid instance don't see other streamers.

GridClient seems don't support streaming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get streamer instance on node which does not have this particular streamer configured. However, you can easily achieve your requirement by providing GridStreamerEventRouter that will not route events on nodes which are not supposed to participate in event processing.

For example, you can use random event router with predicate which will filter nodes by user attribute (you can set user attributes for a node with GridConfiguration.setUserAttributes(...)):

```
GridStreamerConfiguration streamCfg = new GridStreamerConfiguration();
//...
streamCfg.setRouter(new GridStreamerRandomEventRouter(new GridPredicate<GridNode>() {
    @Override public boolean apply(GridNode node) {
        return !"CLIENT".equals(node.attribute("STREAMER_ROLE"));
    }
}));
```

Comment: Is it planned to add some kind of role based router or nodes scope router? I think it would be suitable for many applications, where data is generated in some places, but processed on another nodes (Log processing, statistics aggregation). Also this workaround is limited to RandomRouter and involves configuration via code

Comment: Having a streamer configured on a node does not mean that you need to have processing logic on the same node - simply route your event to the other nodes which will process it. You can easily plugin in your own 'GridStreamerEventRouter' implementation which will route the event based on your specific needs.